# Expand a tree item in flex using its labelName or other fields

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tree, expand

Hi friends here is my requirement:

When I double click an item in the "search" tab that particular item should be opened(expand) in the "Test Group Tree" tab.
The item in the search tab is a **list** and the item in **Test Group Tree** is a TreeItem. According to my knowledge the only way to expand a tree item in other tab is by using its label name(unique).

Here I have used the below mentioned code to implement my requirement. For now the "Test Group Tree" tab opens correctly when i double click in the item in the "search" tab but the SelectedItem is not expanded(opened in the other tab as expected-only the **Test Group Tree** tab opens and nothing else happens). 
Please help me achieve my requirement.

```
private function TSTree_itemDoubleClick(event:ListEvent):void{
    var selectedItem: TSTreeItem = TSTreeItem(TSTreeTestGroup.getSelectedFolderItem());
    this.TSTreeTestGroup.tabMain.selectedIndex=0; // Here i am trying to open a next tab(it works)

    //var selectedSampleItem: TSTreeItem = PLTreeItem(TSTreeTestGroup.treTree.getChildByName(selectedItem.label));
    TestGroupTree(TestGroupManager(this).TSTreeTestGroup).loadPartialTreeItem(selectedItem);  // Here i actually want to refresh the particular tree item       
    TestGroupTree(TestGroupManager(this).TSTreeTestGroup).treTree.expandItem(selectedItem,true,false); // here i am trying to expand the particular tree item
    //TestGroupManager(TestGroupTree(TSTree(event.currentTarget).parentDocument).parentDocument).TSTreeTestGroup.treTree.expandItem(selectedItem, true, false);
    //TestGroupManager(TestGroupTree(TSTree(event.currentTarget).parentDocument).parentDocument).TSTreeTestGroup.loadPartialTreeItem(this.TSTreeTestGroup.treTree.getChildByName(selectedItem.label);
    // in the following i am tryin to get the TreeItemName and expand it accordingly
    TestGroupTree(TestGroupManager(this).TSTreeTestGroup).treTree.expandItem(this.TSTreeTestGroup.treTree.getChildByName(selectedItem.label), true, true);
}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" implements="integras.TS.component.TSTreeComponent"
    show="Component_Show();" 
    remove="Component_Remove();" >
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabMain" change="tabMain_Change();" styleName="plTitleWindowTabNavigator"  creationPolicy="all" >
        <mx:Canvas label="Test Group Tree">
            <ns1:TSTree dataProvider="{dpTree}" updateComplete="treTree_UpdateComplete();" iconFunction="getTreeIcon" labelField="label" iconField="icon" showRoot="false"  allowMultipleSelection="true" id="treTree" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="treTree_ItemDoubleClick(event);"  itemClick="treTree_ItemClick(event);" itemOpen="treTree_ItemOpen(event);" >
            </ns1:TSTree>
        </mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Canvas label="Search" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
            <mx:Canvas>
                <mx:HRule/>
                <mx:List dataProvider="{dpSearch}"  dragEnabled="false" labelField="label" iconField="icon" id="lstSearch" doubleClickEnabled="true" itemDoubleClick="lstSearch_ItemDoubleClick(event);" itemClick="lstSearch_ItemClick(event);">
                </mx:List>
            </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:Box>
```

Thanks in Advance.Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

try searching the selected item in Tree if the found the expand the node.I think the problem may be the selected item what your are passing to tree for expanding.

Check if this sample helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="horizontal" verticalAlign="middle">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.messaging.management.Attribute;
            import mx.events.ListEvent;

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var searchResult:XMLList;
            private var searchResultIndex:uint = 0;

            private function findByLabel(event:Event):void
            {
                var searchStr:String = List(event.currentTarget).selectedItem.@label;
                tabMain.selectedIndex = 0;
                tree.openItems = [];
                //xmlDP.descendants().(@label == List(evt.currentTarget).selectedItem.@label)[0]
                searchResult = xmlDP.descendants().(@label.toLowerCase().search(searchStr.toLowerCase()) > -1);
                searchResultIndex = 0;
                if (searchResult[searchResultIndex] != undefined)
                    expandNode(searchResult[searchResultIndex]);
            }

            private function expandNode(xmlNode:XML):void
            {
                while (xmlNode.parent() != null) {
                    xmlNode = xmlNode.parent();
                    tree.expandItem(xmlNode, true, false);
                }
            }
      ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <!-- Sample tree data -->
     <mx:XML id="xmlDP">
        <root>
                <node label="Parent 1">
                    <node label="Child 1"/>
                    <node label="Child 2">
                        <node label="Grandchild 1"/>
                        <node label="Grandchild 2"/>
                    </node>
                    <node label="Child 3"/>
                    <node label="Child 4"/>
                    <node label="Child 5">
                        <node label="Grandchild 1"/>
                        <node label="Grandchild 2"/>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </root>
    </mx:XML>

    <mx:XMLListCollection id="xmlMenuList" source="{xmlDP.*}"/>


    <mx:XMLList id="listData">
          <data>
            <node label="Parent 1" />
            <node label="Child 1"/>
            <node label="Child 2"/>
            <node label="Grandchild 1"/>
            <node label="Grandchild 2" />
            <node label="Child 3"/>
            <node label="Child 4"/>
            <node label="Child 5"/>
            <node label="Grandchild 1"/>
            <node label="Grandchild 2" />
        </data>
    </mx:XMLList>


    <mx:TabNavigator id="tabMain" creationPolicy="all" width="100%" >
            <mx:Canvas label="Test Group Tree">
                <mx:Tree dataProvider="{xmlMenuList}" labelField="@label" iconField="icon" showRoot="false"  
                         allowMultipleSelection="true" id="tree" doubleClickEnabled="true" width="100%">
                </mx:Tree>
            </mx:Canvas>
            <mx:Canvas label="Search" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                <mx:Canvas width="100%">
                    <mx:HRule/>
                    <mx:List dataProvider="{listData.node}"  dragEnabled="false" labelField="@label" id="lstSearch"
                             width="100%" itemClick="findByLabel(event)">
                    </mx:List>
                </mx:Canvas>
            </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:TabNavigator>


</mx:Application>
```